# Delphi package install error: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed

Tags: delphi, package, components

I'm using Delphi 10.4 (Sydney). I create a simple package containing a unit (with some dependency with other in the search path). It builds OK but when I try to install it I get the error:

**A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed**

I use de "Dependency walker" in the BPL file to check but there all seems to be ok.

I don't know what DLLs is failing to initialize. Is there any way to get more information about what the problem is?

Thank you.

Comment: "*Is there any way to get more information about what the problem is?*" - not really, at least not from the OS itself.  About all you can do is use a tool like [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see which DLLs are being accessed by your process, that might give you some clues.

Comment: A [mcve] is needed here

Answer (score 1):

You can use process monitor to see which dll the program is trying to load

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon